# Linq to SQL grouping with embedded lists causes too many queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am developing a query to grab and join some SQL tables in C# and am having some trouble with grouping and enumerables within the dataset.  My query is below.  This gives me the data in the format I'm looking for, but it takes way too long when I try to add the enumerated list as indicated below.   When I look under the hood I can see it is executing way too many SQL queries.  I'd like to get it to just one.  Using LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var nightlyRuns = (from a in LoadTestSummaries
                join b in LoadTestTestSummaryData
                on a.LoadTestRunId equals b.LoadTestRunId
                where a.TargetStack == "LoadEnv" &&
                a.TestGuid != null &&
                a.StartTime != null &&
                a.LoadTestRunId != null

                orderby a.StartTime
                group new {a, b} by new
                {
                    a.TestGuid,
                    a.Name,
                    a.Description,
                    a.StartTime,
                    a.Duration,
                    a.NumAgents,
                    a.NumHosts,
                    a.PassFail,
                    a.ResultsFilePath,
                    a.Splunk
                } 
                into g
                let scenarioStart = g.Min(s => s.a.StartTime) ?? g.Min(s => s.a.DateCreated)        
                let testCases = g.Select(s => s.b)
                orderby scenarioStart 
                select new 
                {
                    TestGuid = g.Key.TestGuid,
                    ScenarioRun = new 
                    {
                        Name = g.Key.Name,
                        Description = g.Key.Description,
                        StartTime = scenarioStart,
                        Duration = g.Key.Duration,
                        NumAgents = g.Key.NumAgents,
                        NumHosts = g.Key.NumHosts,
                        Result = g.Key.PassFail,
                        ResultsFilePath = g.Key.ResultsFilePath,
                        SplunkLink = g.Key.Splunk,
                        // PROBLEM: Causes too many queries:
                        TestRuns = from t in testCases select t.TestCaseId
                    }
                }).ToLookup(g => g.TestGuid, g => g.ScenarioRun);

    nightlyRuns["ba593f66-695f-4fd1-99c3-71253a2e4981"].Dump();
}
```

The "TestRuns" line is causing the excessive queries.  Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Are the foreign keys set up properly in your database and entities? Normally a join wouldn't be needed here when using Linq to entities oif theFKs are correct.

Comment: Sadly not -- I suppose I could add the FK but I don't own the code that writes to the tables so I would also need to add a trigger to fill this in.  I will try that if I'm not able to come to a solution.  For now I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's a big question brian, I wish I could have left my answer as a comment, but if you check out what I have, and the link, it should help unless I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Tough answer to test but I think we can avoid the grouping and multiple queries with something like this: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

```
           var nightlyRuns = (from a in LoadTestSummaries
            join b in LoadTestTestSummaryData
            on a.LoadTestRunId equals b.LoadTestRunId
            where a.TargetStack == "LoadEnv" &&
            a.TestGuid != null &&
            a.StartTime != null &&
            a.LoadTestRunId != null
            into testGroup

            select new 
            {
                TestGuid = a.TestGuid,
                ScenarioRun = new 
                {
                    Name = a.TestGuid,
                    Description = a.Description,
                    StartTime = a.StartTime ?? a.DateCreated,
                    Duration = a.Duration,
                    NumAgents = g.Key.NumAgents,
                    NumHosts = a.NumHosts,
                    Result = a.PassFail,
                    ResultsFilePath = a.ResultsFilePath,
                    SplunkLink = a.Splunk,
                    // PROBLEM: Causes too many queries:
                    TestRuns =testGroup
                }
            }).OrderBy(x=>x.StartTime).ToLookup(x => x.TestGuid, x => x.ScenarioRun);

            nightlyRuns["ba593f66-695f-4fd1-99c3-71253a2e4981"].Dump();
```

Comment: I don't quite follow the "into testGroup" here?  Did you intend to group?

Comment: Oh nevermind, the "into testGroup" should come after "on" and before "where".  This definitely reduces it to just one query, very helpful, thank you.  Something is up with "StartTime" but I should be able to figure that out.  Will post back...

Comment: Suppose I want to add something from table b in the select for the ScenarioRun anonymous type.  For example:

Comment: Pressed enter too soon.  For example, if I want Duration = b.Duration above, how can I get table b into the grouping?  I see "The name 'd' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Ah nevermind, think I figured it out.  Getting my tables mixed up!